# How to populate a table with data from tables on other sheets using a drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I am trying to populate a main table using a drop down list whereby each dropdown option extracts data from a table from its respective sheet. All the tables are of the same dimensions.

Example: I have 3 populated tables for Types of insurance claim down the y axis (public liability, flood, fire), and whether these claims are 3, 2 or 1 year old across the x axis. The values will be how many of these claim have been made, separating them by age. The three tables are then based on whether these claims are under review, partial payment has been made, or no formal claim has been made respectively.

I want to use a drop down in an empty table to alternate between these three tables.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [VLOOKUP](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/vlookup-a-guide-to-searching-for-data/) or [INDEX & MATCH](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/index-match-better-way-look-data/) functions?
You can summon whole table by placing row and column indexes for whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dtermine the value range for 3 table as 3 names first:

[image]

Then use INDIRECT function to return the data based on the dropdown list, enter the array formula to this Range:

```
=INDIRECT($A$1)
```

Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

[image]

Then you will get the result:

[image]